# Creating an ellipsoidal 3D surface

Tags: geometry, matlab, 3d, surfaces

I am trying to find the equation of a 3D ellipsoidal surface. I have thought of two approaches which are schematically shown below:

By revolving an elliptical arc over a 3D elliptical path:

[image: First Approach]

Or by scaling an elliptical arc while translating in $z$-direction:

[image: Second Approach]

I thought the first approach (revolving) is easier. Here is my description of what I have done. The elliptical arc segment, which lies in $xy$-plane, that revolves around $y$-axis on an elliptical path (non-circular) to create a 3D ellipsoidal surface.

The revolving elliptical segment has the following equation ($0<\theta\le\pi/2$):

$$\frac{x^2}{R_x^2}+\frac{y^2}{R_y^2} = 1,\mathrm{\ \ \ or\ \ \ } \begin{cases}
    x = R_x\cos\left(\theta\right)\\
    y = R_y\sin\left(\theta\right)
  \end{cases}$$

The revolving angle is called $\phi$ and revolves $0<\phi\le\pi/2$ in the $xz$-plane according to the following elliptical path:

$$\frac{x^2}{{R^\prime}_x^2}+\frac{z^2}{R_z^2} = 1, \mathrm{\ \ \ or\ \ \ } \begin{cases}
    x = {R^\prime}_x\cos\left(\phi\right)\\
    z = R_z\sin\left(\phi\right)
  \end{cases}$$

While revolving I want to scale down $R_y$ according to $\phi$:

$$R_y = h\cos\left(\phi\right)$$

where $h$ is a constant. So, as the elliptical arc revolves by $\phi$, $R_y$ decreases and so as $R_x$.

In the $\phi$-plane, the points on the revolved ellipse has the following equations:

$$\begin{cases}
    x = {\left(\left[{{R^\prime}_x}\cos\left(\phi\right)\right]^2+\left[R_z\sin\left(\phi\right)\right]^2\right)}^\frac12\cos\left(\theta\right)\\
    y = h\cos\left(\phi\right)\sin\left(\theta\right)\\
z = R_z\sin\left(\phi\right)
  \end{cases}$$

When I plot the above parametric equations in `MATLAB` I don't get the expected surface. Could someone kindly help me?

```
% Here is the MATLAB code I used.
Rx = 1;
Rz = 1;
h  = 2;

n = 100;
[theta, phi] = meshgrid(linspace(0,pi/2,n), linspace(0,pi/2,n));

x = (Rx^2*cos(phi).^2+Rz^2*sin(phi).^2).^0.5.*cos(theta);
y = h*cos(phi).*sin(theta);
z = Rz*sin(phi);

surf(x,y,z), shading interp, axis equal, xlabel('x'), ylabel('y'), zlabel('z')
```

Here is the `MATLAB` result:

[image]

Comment: I don't get it. What is it you are trying to do? Do you want to plot something, or is plotting just a means of checking if your equations are correct?

Comment: I tried to better clarify my question in this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1072458/62050

Comment: So this is a duplicate? Are you looking for this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid#Parameterization ?

Comment: This is not a duplicate and the Wikipedia information is not what I want. In the link I provided, I approached differently.

Comment: Ok I guess by *elliptical* you don't necessarily mean a linear transformation of a circle? Am I correct to say, that what you want is an equation for the surface you drew: a straight line in the z-direction, a circle in the x-direction, and something that looks a lot like an ellipsoid in between?

Comment: I think that might look like it. The projection to xy plane is an elliptical arc,  the projection to xz plane is another elliptical arc, and probably the projection to yz plane is a straight line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should fulfill your requirements. It is the subsurface of an elliptical $z$-axis cylinder $(x/R_x)^2 + (y/R_y)^2 = 1$, that is contained within the filled elliptical $y$-axis cylinder $(x/R_x)^2 + (z/R_z)^2 < 1$.

$$M:=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : (x/R_x)^2 + (y/R_y)^2 = 1; (x/R_x)^2 + (z/R_z)^2 < 1 \textrm{ and } x>0, z>0\}$$

```
Rx = 3;
Ry = 2;
Rz = 6;

n = 100;
x = linspace(0,Rx,n);
z = linspace(0,Rz,n);
[U, V] = ndgrid(x, z);

X = U.*sqrt((1-(V/Rz).^2));
Y = sqrt((1-(X/Rx).^2)*Ry^2);
Z = V;
surf(Z,X,Y); % The ordering is just swapped so we can rotate it more easily!
xlabel('z'), ylabel('x'), zlabel('y');
shading interp;
axis equal; axis vis3d;
```

[image]

Comment: knedlsepp: Thanks for the great answer. Could you please let me know of your thoughts on [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1077284/62050)?