# The equation of a 3D surface bounded by 3 known elliptical curves

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, surfaces

I am trying to find the equation of a 3D surface as illustrated below. The boundaries of this surface is comprised of two planar elliptical arcs $AB$ and $AC$ as well as a 3D arc $BC$ which is a 3D curve on an elliptical surface described nicely in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1075515/62050). Could someone kindly help me how this surface bounded by $AB$, $AC$, and $BC$ can be put into an equation? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: It seems to me you are trying to do some geometric modeling. Why not use a modeling software? What are you doing with all these equations?

Comment: I want to use `MATLAB` to generate this geometry and the one I posted previously. I want to then computationally model their mechanical behavior under certain conditions.

Comment: So you are doing architecture? Do you already know how to solve the mechanical behavior part?

Comment: It will be finite element analysis. Having the equation of the geometry, I can perform parametric study.

Comment: So what about some modeling software? I think this could get you a lot further.

Comment: I understand that. But the main purpose of this is to be able to parametrically perform the analysis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19664/discussion-between-a2009-and-knedlsepp).

Answer (score 1):

with a parametrized solution you might have a parameter for a point M between  A and B and another for the point on the ellipsoid between C and M

Comment: Point $M$ between $A$ and $B$ is easy to formulate parametrically. How would the point between $C$ and $M$ be described?

Answer (score 1):

We can try to approach this as an interpolation problem. Sample the arcs in a few middle points, you'll get a dataset $(x_i, y_i, z_i)$, albeit only at the boundaries. Such highly irregular scattered data interpolation could be dealt with by using radial basis functions, with the thin plate spline as a natural kernel for stress analysis. The RBF interpolant will be a sum of as many terms as there were points, but it is a function you can evaluate on your FEM mesh inside the patch.